# getting compiz back after removing

Tags: compiz

I installed SPSS on 12.04, there was some graphic problem, the screen turned blank. so, i tried to improve by removing compiz. now I want to get it back. but the sofware center wont install it as it says that "There isn’t a software package called “compiz-core” in your current software sources." what should I do? :/

Answer (score 0):

Update source.list file :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Open terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-plugins-main compiz-plugins
```

Open compiz :

```
ccsm
```